# How to generate SMI interrupt programmatically

Tags: assembly, instructions

SMI interrupt can be received to `SMI#` pin (e.g from chipset). But how i can signam SMI interrupt programmatically (e.g. with `Int` instruction)? There is no in an [intel developers manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.pdf) reserved interrupt vector for `SMI`.

Comment: See the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Mode) - `Software SMI triggered by the system software via an I/O access to a location considered special by the motherboard logic (port 0B2h is common).`